# Angular google maps window html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I am trying to render some HTML in a window using angular google maps.  Here is my code:

```
<ui-gmap-window coords="homeWindow.coordinates" idKey="homeWindow._id" show="homeWindow.showWindow" closeClick="homeWindow.closeClick">
  <div>
    <a class="media-left">
      <img class="resultThumb" src="assets/images/houseicon.png" />
    </a>
    <div class="media-body">
      <h3 class="media-heading">{{homeWindow.listing.listprice[0] | currency: '$':0}}</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</ui-gmap-window>
```

When I leave the image tag in the window will not pop up at all.  When I remove it however it seems to popup but the window doesn't fit the content inside.  When I just render an image it seems to work fine.  Overall the output seems to be weird and inconsistent and I can't seem to get a handle on truly how it works. What am I missing?

Comment: What version of angular are you using?

Comment: Angular update might intefere with maps api sometimes.

Comment: angular: 1.3.8, angular-google-maps: 2.0.6